# Issues writing a binary search program

Tags: java, debugging, binary-search

I am a beginning programmer who is trying to write a simple binary search program. I have messed around with this program with several days but have not had any luck getting it to run as it should. I keep getting the errors double cannot be derefrenced and possible loss of precision when I try to compile the program in java. Thanks you very much for any help you can give.

The program in question is right below. ( I have used the example from a book I have but even that I have not been able to get it to work quite right) Someone said that I should tell the exact errors and they are double could not be derefrenced `if( a[ mid ].compareTo( x ) < 0 )` and double could not be dereferenced `else if( a[ mid ].compareTo( x ) > 0)`.

**EDIT:** I have received some help and have changed some doubles to integers

```
public class Search
{
    public static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    public static double binarySearch(double[] a , double x)
    {
        int low=0;
        int high = a.length -1;
        int mid;
        while( low <= high )
        {
            mid = ( low + high ) / 2;

            if( a[ mid ].compareTo( x ) < 0 )
                low = mid + 1;
            else if( a[ mid ].compareTo( x ) > 0)
                high = mid - 1;
            else 
                return mid;
        }
        return NOT_FOUND;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        int SIZE = 6;
        double[] a = {-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5};
        for (int i= 0; i<SIZE ; i++)
        a[i] = new Integer(i *2);
        for (int i= 0; i<SIZE*2; i++)
            System.out.println("Found" + i + " at " + binarySearch(a, 45.3 ));
    }
}
```

Comment: At least tell us the exact and complete error messages you get.

Comment: Also, a is a double array. Why do you store Integer inside? Store doubles in a double array. And indices in an array are ints. Don't use doubles to store integer indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `double low` and friends to reference indexes in the array. You need to use `int`s for this.

```
int low = 0;
int high = a.length - 1;
int mid;
```

You're also overwriting your values here:

```
double[] a = {-3,10,5,24,45.3,10.5};
for (int i= 0; i<SIZE ; i++)
    a[i] = new Integer(i *2);
```

You start with `a` with the values of `-3, 10, 5...` but then you immediate overwrite them with `0, 2, 4 ...` in a for loop there. I'm not sure why...

But those are just kind of side notes. The reason it won't compile is that you're trying to use `compareTo()` on a `double` - now it should be autoboxing, but for whatever reason it isn't. So instead, you need to use `Double.compare(a[low],x)`. It has the added bonus of saving Object creations.

Comment: That helps a lot but I am still getting that double cannot be derefrenced error

Comment: Did you make the change at the bottom about `Double.compare(a[low],x)` instead of `a[low].compareTo(x)`?

Comment: yeah and my errors bloomed from 2 to 57. I really don't get why it would do that as far as I can see you are right and it would just avoid object creation, but it did. I also got rid of that bit at the end that was causing replacement problems. It was leftover from the code I started with as an example ut i guess I had forgotten it was in there

Comment: That's good! The compiler goes in phases. It checks one set of things, then another set, and so on. If you went from 2 to 57, it's probably because you made it past one set of possible errors, and now it's giving you a whole new set of errors to fix. That's a great thing, because you're closer to getting it to compile.

Comment: Oh I figured it out. The problem was that you had double.compare(a[low],x) and it was originally and needed to be changed to a[mid]. Thank you so much for all the help. This was really frustrating me and I an very happy that you were able to help me. Thanks again

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Whoops. My bad. But the change from `.compareTo` to `.compare` is a good one :-)

Answer (score 1):

`double cannot be dereferenced` comes from the "I'm not sure how it even makes it this far" issue of your `Integer`s.

First, you declare `a` to be a `double[]`.  Then, you assign each value in `a` to be an `Integer`.  I'm guessing that the language might be transparently converting it back to double for you, but I'm not sure on that one.

Your error comes from the part where you wrote `a[ mid ].compareTo( x )`.  `a` is a `double[]`.  Thus, `a[mid]` is a `double`.  `double`s are not objects, and thus cannot be "dereferenced".  using the `.compareTo()` method is attempting exactly that.  It would be similar to writing `9.compareTo(7)`.

I would suggest not using the `Integer` or `Double` classes for this case, and just using straight arithmetic:

```
        if( a[ mid ] < x )
            low = mid + 1;
        else if( a[ mid ] > x)
            high = mid - 1;
```

As for your main loop, try

```
public static void main( String[] args)
{
    int SIZE = 6;
    double[] a = {-3,5,10,10.5,24,45.3};

    System.out.println("Found 45.3 at " + binarySearch(a, 45.3 ));
}
```

Although you will need to sort a (as I did by hand, or with a `sort()` method) for a binary search to work properly.

Comment: Good explanation though I'm not sure I completely agree with not ever using `Integer` or `Double`, but I'm a noob -what do I know? :-/

Comment: I was about to indignantly respond "For this case, not in general; they have a number of legitimate uses", and then I noticed that I did use the word 'ever'.  Editing for clarity now.  -- It appears I meant to type 'even', not 'ever'.  'even' makes much more sense in context.

Comment: Ahh.. that makes much more sense haha!